# How to add a MIME type in IIS via windows command line

Tags: windows, command-line, iis, mime-types

How can I add a MIME type (file type) like `.apk` to IIS via command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config /section:staticContent /+"[fileExtension='.apk',mimeType='application/vnd.android.package-archive']"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config /section:staticContent /+"[fileExtension='.apk',mimeType='application/vnd.android.package-archive']"
```